# not injecting "data-turbolinks": false

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am using:

- ruby "2.3.1"
- gem "rails", "5.0.0.1"
- gem "turbolinks", "~> 5.0.0.beta"
- gem "semantic-ui-sass" ... on this page

I have 2 links on the page:

````
<p><%= link_to("Back to Dashboard", dashboard_path, "data-turbolinks": false) %></p>```
````

it correctly injects the turoblinks into the HTML:

```
<a data-turbolinks="false" href="/dashboard">Back to Dashboard</a>
```

But when I add it into the loop here...

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= link_to(contact.display_full_name, lead, "data-turbolinks": false) %></td>
</tr>

<a href="/leads/11">Bob Smith</a>
```

It does not include `data-turbolinks="false"`

Any suggestions?
Many thanks.

Comment: `<%= link_to("Back to Dashboard", dashboard_path, data: { no_turbolink: true } %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per turbolink gem [documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/tree/v5.0.0.beta5#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links)

```
<a href="/" data-turbolinks="false">Disabled</a>
```

`data-turbolinks` value should be string "false" not Boolean.

try like this:

```
<%= link_to("Back to Dashboard", dashboard_path, "data-turbolinks": "false")

<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= link_to(contact.display_full_name, lead, "data-turbolinks": "false") %></td>
            </tr>
 %>
```

It should work.

Comment: sorry - bit confused - the  code you state above is teh exact code i have.  It works for the Dashboard but not when it is put in the loop.  ``` link_to("Back to Dashboard", dashboard_path, "data-turbolinks": false)```

Comment: @user2970050 Try my updated answer. It is "false"(string) not the false(Boolean).

Comment: Yes - actually,  your first recommendation worked.  i am going to removed some of my comments in case anyone else refers to this question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **haml** in **rails**, it will work in the following way:

```
= link_to "/dashboard", class: "active", :data => {turbolinks: "false" }
```